# Solaris NFS Mount Permissions

Tags: nfs, solaris

I've created an NFS share and have added to vfstab. However, I'm not able to change permissions or create directories as ROOT on the server where it is mounted.

```
$ mkdir test
mkdir: Failed to make directory "test"; Permission denied
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

In general NFS servers don't give root on the client root access. You need to explicitly share the filesytem to the client with root=

You don't say which version of Solaris you're using or file system type so can't give detailed instructions. Look at the documentation for share (or just google for "solaris nfs share root")

Comment: Where is the root= option set in Solaris?